# Add Google Allow-List to MySQL Server Config File

Tags: mysql, google-sheets, whitelist

Despite extensive searching, I have not found the syntax for adding ~70 URLs in the [Google Allow-List](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt) to the my.ini config file, presumably using some form of `bind-address`?

Although I have successfully established a connection, using `bind-address=0.0.0.0`, I would like to restrict access to that list.

Should they be entered as one long comma-separated string after the `bind-address=` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 8.0.13 and higher support a comma-separated list of IP addresses as the value of `bind-address`.

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bind_address

Older versions of MySQL don't support this feature. Run `SELECT VERSION();` If it's less than 8.0.13, you must either upgrade to the current version of 8.0.x, or else solve this with a firewall of some kind (e.g. iptables), instead of MySQL's `bind-address` option.

Comment: Thanks Bill, Google has not been my friend today! One question, as I have to add 70 urls, do they have to be on "one" line, or can I break them into a few separate lines providing I keep using the comma separator?

Comment: NO GO !!!  I tried multiple numbers of URLs, then tried the very first Google url, and in each case, the server would not start. I note from the documentation that "If binding to any address fails, the server produces an error and does not start.".

Comment: What is your version of MySQL?

Comment: It's a new installation... 8.0.26.   After many failures with less and less of the 71 urls, I tried just the first one in my.ini - bind_address=8.8.4.0/24, and the server would not start. I've reverted to 0.0.0.0.  Also searched every setting in my modem/router, can't find anything on adding "iptables".